# general issue about creating views

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have got a rather basic question but I could not find a confirmation about it online. When you create a view like the one below

```
 create view report AS
 select employee_id
 from employees
```

It will store the data in a virtual table. That's ok. But when you add additional employee ids AFTER you have created the view will they be displayed when you run the view again? Cuz what I need is basically some view that will display the latest records I have added in the tables. Is that possible?

Comment: Views do not "_store the data in a virtual table_", unless they are _materialized views_, which I believe is not the case here.

Comment: So? Will it display data that's been added to the underlying tables after the view's been created??

Comment: Yes, every time you select from the view (as SELECT * FROM REPORT), you will get the "latest records", because essentially, the underlying query will be executed every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is Yes, it will update....

Ok, so Views don't quite "store" data, they just present data in a different format or select certain columns from a table to create your own "view" of the data.

If you are just looking to find the most recent employee ids through a view, I would recommend adding a column with a created or modified date field defaulting to the date entered. Then have your table do an Order By the datefield descending and select only top few rows so you only get recent records. The way to do this is slightly different depending on if you are using SQL, Oracle, or MySQL.